Probability related to the lengths of the arcs formed by three random points
We take three points $A,B,C$ at random on the boundary of the unit circle:

We have then three arcs WLOG with lengths $$l_{AB} \le l_{BC} \le l_{CA}$$.
How can we compute the probability that both $$l_{AB} \le {2\pi \over 3}\quad\mbox{and}\quad l_{BC} \le {2\pi \over 3}\ {\large ?}$$.
I am asking this because I think the answer would solve the case $k=n=3$ of this question but I am not able to do it [EDIT: probably this point is wrong].

Any hint ?.

The shortest arc is certainly $\le {2\pi \over 3}$.

Ok @Henry but is it easy then calculating the probability that the second shortest arc length is also $\le 2\pi/3$?

This is equivalent to dividing a segment $[0,L]$ (where $L=2\pi$ but it's not essential) by choosing two independent $U[0,L]$ random variables, say $X_1$ and $X_2$. You are asking if the lenghts of the two smallest segments  are each less than $L/3$.
Now assume wlog $L=1$.
Let us sort $X$ in an increasing order $X_{(1)}<X_{(2)}$, so the lengths of the three segments are
$$
\xi_1=X_{(1)}-0,\  \xi_2=X_{(2)}-X_{(1)},\  \xi_2=1-X_{(2)}.
$$
Note that if any two segments are each smaller than $L/3$, then the remaining one is larger and thus they are indeed the smallest two. Hence we are interested in probability
\begin{align}
&\mathbb P(\xi_1,\xi_2<L/3\text{ or }\xi_2,\xi_3<L/3\text{ or }\xi_3,\xi_1<L/3)
\\
&=\mathbb P(\xi_1,\xi_2<L/3)+\mathbb P(\xi_3,\xi_2<L/3)+\mathbb P(\xi_1,\xi_3<L/3)
\end{align}
since these events are in fact disjoint (all of them cannot be smaller than $L/3$ at the same time as they sum up to $L$).
Now recall that the joint denssity of $X_{(1)},X_{(2)}$ is
$f(x,y)=2\times 1_{0<x<y<1}$
We have
$$
\mathbb P(\xi_1,\xi_2<L/3)=\iint_{x<\frac13,x<y<x+\frac13} 2dxdy=\frac29,
$$
$$
\mathbb P(\xi_2,\xi_3<L/3)=\iint_{0<y-x<\frac13,1-y<\frac13} 2dxdy=\frac29,
$$
$$
\mathbb P(\xi_3,\xi_1<L/3)=\iint_{0<x<\frac13,1-y<\frac13} 2dxdy=\frac29,
$$
(which all are equal by the symmetry anyway!) so the answer is $\frac29\times 3=\frac 23$.

Thank you. Three things: 1. I think last row should be $2/9 \times 3 = 2/3$. 2. How do you get the second integral? 3. In my numerical simulations for the linked question I obtained a probability of $2/3$ there, therefore I would have expected $1-2/3=1/3$ here, unless I made an error in my simulations.

Yes. extra 2 was a typo (corrected). In fact, you do not need to compute the second and the third integral as by symmetry they should be the same as the first one, but if  you really want to compute one do it as $\int_{2/3}^1 (\int_{y-1/3}^y 2  dx)dy=\int_{2/3}^1 \frac23 dy=\frac29$. (I can't comment on the simulations)

Ok, so maybe my conclusion that the condition that we cannot cut the pizza like in the linked question, is the condition of my question here, is wrong.

import numpy as np  
N = 100000  # Number of simulations
# Counter for events where the two distance is less than 1/3
count = 0
# Simulation
for _ in range(N):
    # Simulate two points independently and uniformly on [0, 1]
    X = np.random.uniform(0, 1)
    Y = np.random.uniform(0, 1)     
    # Calculate lengths
    xi1 = min(X,Y)
    xi2 = abs(X-Y)
    xi3 = 1-max(X,Y)
    smallest_two = sorted([xi1, xi2, xi3])[:2]
    if smallest_two[0] < 1/3 and smallest_two[1] < 1/3:
        count += 1
print(f"Estimated probability: {count/N:.4f}")

